# How to wire up a custom notification system in React/Redux?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux

I'm creating a web app in React/Redux, and I am still new to the framework.  So far, I've created a `SignIn` view component which will call the `signInUser` action creator.  This action uses `thunk` to dispatch the appropriate action when the AJAX call is resolved/rejected all from within my `user-actions.js` file.

Separately, I've created a `Notification` view component.  I have a `addNotification` action and `notificationReducer` to go with it.  This may receive notifications other than ones that deal with user sign in.

When the AJAX request is rejected, I want the `Notification` component to update and display the error.  When the `signInUser` action gets rejected it calls the `addNotification` action from the `notification-actions.js` file.  The `notificationReducer` updates the state and the `Notification` component shows the notification.

I've tried to diagram this below:
[image]

Is this a good way to structure the communication between actions and components?  Is there a better practice I should consider?

*(NOTE: I'm already using react, redux, react-router, thunk in my project.  I would like to avoid using another library just so I can't better understand how to set things up properly between React and Redux.)*

Comment: I see no obvious problems with this - having the notifications split out into their own reducer/actions seems smart. I'd probably structure it the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this would be the preferred way to do it. I created something very similar to this about a year ago. This is how I set it up..

Few things to note first.. this is in typescript so you would need to remove the type declarations :)

I am using the npm packages `lodash` for operations, and `classnames` (cx alias) for inline classname assignment.

The beauty of this setup is I use a unique identifier for each notification when the action creates it. (e.g. notify_id). This unique ID is a `Symbol()`. This way if you want to remove any notification at any point in time you can because you know which one to remove. This notification system will let you stack as many as you want and they will go away when the animation is completed. I am hooking into the animation event and when it finishes I trigger some code to remove the notification. I also setup a fallback timeout to remove the notification  just incase the animation callback doesn't fire.

### notification-actions.ts

```
import { USER_SYSTEM_NOTIFICATION } from '../constants/action-types';

interface IDispatchType {
    type: string;
    payload?: any;
    remove?: Symbol;
}

export const notifySuccess = (message: any, duration?: number) => {
    return (dispatch: Function) => {
        dispatch({ type: USER_SYSTEM_NOTIFICATION, payload: { isSuccess: true, message, notify_id: Symbol(), duration } } as IDispatchType);
    };
};

export const notifyFailure = (message: any, duration?: number) => {
    return (dispatch: Function) => {
        dispatch({ type: USER_SYSTEM_NOTIFICATION, payload: { isSuccess: false, message, notify_id: Symbol(), duration } } as IDispatchType);
    };
};

export const clearNotification = (notifyId: Symbol) => {
    return (dispatch: Function) => {
        dispatch({ type: USER_SYSTEM_NOTIFICATION, remove: notifyId } as IDispatchType);
    };
};
```

### notification-reducer.ts

```
const defaultState = {
    userNotifications: []
};

export default (state: ISystemNotificationReducer = defaultState, action: IDispatchType) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_SYSTEM_NOTIFICATION:
            const list: ISystemNotification[] = _.clone(state.userNotifications) || [];
            if (_.has(action, 'remove')) {
                const key = parseInt(_.findKey(list, (n: ISystemNotification) => n.notify_id === action.remove));
                if (key) {
                    // mutate list and remove the specified item
                    list.splice(key, 1);
                }
            } else {
                list.push(action.payload);
            }
            return _.assign({}, state, { userNotifications: list });
    }
    return state;
};
```

### app.tsx

in the base render for your application you would render the notifications

```
render() {
    const { systemNotifications } = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            <AppHeader />
            <div className="user-notify-wrap">
                { _.get(systemNotifications, 'userNotifications') && Boolean(_.get(systemNotifications, 'userNotifications.length'))
                    ? _.reverse(_.map(_.get(systemNotifications, 'userNotifications', []), (n, i) => <UserNotification key={i} data={n} clearNotification={this.props.actions.clearNotification} />))
                    : null
                }
            </div>
            <div className="content">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

### user-notification.tsx

user notification class

```
/*
    Simple notification class.

    Usage:
        <SomeComponent notifySuccess={this.props.notifySuccess} notifyFailure={this.props.notifyFailure} />
        these two functions are actions and should be props when the component is connect()ed

    call it with either a string or components. optional param of how long to display it (defaults to 5 seconds)
        this.props.notifySuccess('it Works!!!', 2);
        this.props.notifySuccess(<SomeComponentHere />, 15);
        this.props.notifyFailure(<div>You dun goofed</div>);

*/

interface IUserNotifyProps {
    data: any;
    clearNotification(notifyID: symbol): any;
}

export default class UserNotify extends React.Component<IUserNotifyProps, {}> {
    public notifyRef = null;
    private timeout = null;

    componentDidMount() {
        const duration: number = _.get(this.props, 'data.duration', '');

        this.notifyRef.style.animationDuration = duration ? `${duration}s` : '5s';


        // fallback incase the animation event doesn't fire
        const timeoutDuration = (duration * 1000) + 500;
        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.notifyRef.classList.add('hidden');
            this.props.clearNotification(_.get(this.props, 'data.notify_id') as symbol);
        }, timeoutDuration);

        TransitionEvents.addEndEventListener(
            this.notifyRef,
            this.onAmimationComplete
        );
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);

        TransitionEvents.removeEndEventListener(
            this.notifyRef,
            this.onAmimationComplete
        );
    }
    onAmimationComplete = (e) => {
        if (_.get(e, 'animationName') === 'fadeInAndOut') {
            this.props.clearNotification(_.get(this.props, 'data.notify_id') as symbol);
        }
    }
    handleCloseClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.clearNotification(_.get(this.props, 'data.notify_id') as symbol);
    }
    assignNotifyRef = target => this.notifyRef = target;
    render() {
        const {data, clearNotification} = this.props;
        return (
            <div ref={this.assignNotifyRef} className={cx('user-notification fade-in-out', {success: data.isSuccess, failure: !data.isSuccess})}>
                {!_.isString(data.message) ? data.message : <h3>{data.message}</h3>}
                <div className="close-message" onClick={this.handleCloseClick}>+</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

### user-notify.less

```
@white: #FFFFFF;
@green: #58ba68;
@charcoal: #404040;
@warning-red: #e63c3c;

.user-notify-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 1rem;
    left: 1rem;
    min-width: 20rem;
    z-index: 2000;

    .user-notification {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        color: @white;
        background-color: @charcoal;

        margin-top: 1rem;
        padding: 1rem 2.5rem 1rem 1rem;
        border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.12),0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.24);

        opacity: 0;

        transition: all .5s;

        &:first-child {
            margin-top: 0;
        }

        &.success {
            background-color: @green;
        }
        &.failure {
            /*background-image: linear-gradient(to right, @faded-red, @purple);*/
            background-color: @warning-red;
        }

        &.fade-in-out {
            animation: fadeInAndOut forwards;
        }

        &.hidden {
            height: 0;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: none;
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        .close-message {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            right: 1rem;
            font-size: 2rem;
            color: @white;
            cursor: pointer;
            transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        * {
            color: @white;
            font-size: 1.125rem;
        }
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
            color: @white !important;
            margin: 0 !important;
            font-family: Lato;
            padding: 0 1rem;
        }
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInAndOut {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    10% { opacity: 1; }
    90% { opacity: 1; }
    99% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { display: none !important; visibility: none !important; height: 0 !important; width: 0 !important; }
}
```

Comment: Nicely done!  I like the idea of using Symbols as the unique identifier too.